# Switching on/off iCloud on iPad causes app to crash

Tags: ios, ipad, settings, icloud, documents

I have an iCloud enabled app which works well.  However, on testing, when my app is running and I either switch off or on Documents & Data for my specific app, via iCloud Settings, it crashes.

The only information for my crash in xCode is the call-stack...as shown.  Otherwise, I'm at a loss.   Any ideas?[image]

My setup is this...

I am using iOS v7.1.2/Xcode 5.1.1
I am 'backing-up' snapshots of my database (zip files) in an iCloud folder known as 'Backup'...I'm assuming Apple would be OK with this setup, rather than copying everything to the documents folder.

[image]

I do at a certain point in my program create a use an NSMetaDataQuery to monitor the Backup folder but it is nil most of the time and not operating.

The system will crash at any point of the program if I change the setting in the Documents and Data part of iCloud config...(My Test App)
[image]

Note...Switching on or off the main Documents and Data UISwitch has no effect and app does not crash.

Other than that, there's not a lot going on. The zip file is simply copied to iCloud.

Comment: Need more information, such as (1) what version of iOS? (2) what iCloud API (Core Data, UIDocument, k/v store)? (3) how does your app actually use this API? (4) are you listening for any iCloud notifications, and if so, what do you do when they're posted?

Comment: Hi Tom.  Have updated the info. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Interesting....This problem seems to manifest itself on other apps I have running under xCode as well but when I run the apps independently on the iPad, they don't crash.  Must be something to do with my Mc/xCode/iPad setup, so may not be actually a problem.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same thing here... Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Seems to be causing strange behaviour even if I run the app from the device.

Comment: Nope. Still causes problem. It's not a big issue in the great scheme of things for me, but I wonder if it's an iOS bug.

Comment: I noticed that the app receives a `applicationWillTerminate:` before closing, which means it's not an actual crash, but just some strange behavior in iOS.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem testing my app on the simulator. Did you get any progress on this?

Comment: Firstly, are you watching NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification? You then need to check [NSFileManager defaultManager].ubiquityIdentityToken to see if you are logged onto iCloud and take appropriate action. In my experience crashes can occur with the simulator, but a real device will behave as you would expect.